# Models which Arima can not calculate and produce error

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying some models over some data and some models produce error on `Forecast::Arima` function. I have write `ErrorHandler` with `try catch` but this is also slowing down the process. Can I know in someway the models that Arima can not calculate and give error? So that I can just skip those models.It is a classical Arima functin. Here it is, 
`Arima(a, order = c(p,d,q), seasonal = list(order = c(P,D,Q), period = periyot), method="ML")` 
I am iterating p,q, P,Q values in nested for loops.

```
abv <- Arima(cotton.ts, order = c(3,1,3), seasonal = list(order = c(2,1,3), period = 24))
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

An example of an error is given.

Comment: What error is thrown? Where is the code you've written?

Comment: It is a classical Arima functin. Here it is, `Arima(a, order = c(p,d,q), seasonal = list(order = c(P,D,Q), period = periyot),
          method="ML")`

Comment: What is the error it throws? Also, it will be more helpful to others if you edit that code into the post

Comment: edited. @MattSandgren

Comment: What happens if you set `hessian = FALSE`?

Comment: it is not an argument I guess. Unused argument error is thrown. @MattSandgren

Comment: Try omitting the method parameter so it uses the default method- I think ML may be giving problematic Hessians here

Comment: Nope. as you see in the example, I didn't use method and still getting error. @MattSandgren